# How to partial training on the additional data for pre-trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In my case, I would like to weekly tune/adjust the model parameters value.
I have pre-trained the model by using the 100K data rows, Keras, and saved the model.
Then, as the new data collection (10K data rows), I need to tune the model parameter but don't want to retrain the whole dataset (110K).

How can I just partially fit the data on the model? load model -> model.fit(10K_data)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct you will train only on the new dataset (10k) `model.fit(10K_data)`. I will recommend to change the learning rate for the retraining **(reducing the learning rate)** as you will just want to do a minor update to the parameters while keeping the earlier learning intact (or trying to leavarage the earlier learning).

Comment: But `model.fit()` is not helpful in case of incremental training.. what it does is it will retrain the entire model. 

So if weekly new data is coming and you use _fit()_ method to retrain an entire model every week, a stage will come where data gets too large, and it won't fit into the memory...

So in my opinion, `fit_partial()` should be the right approach for training a model in production.